# Unable to install openvpn-2.3.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to work work with TUN/TAP

Tags: ubuntu, network-programming

I'm trying to install openvpn-2.3.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to work with TUN/TAP.

I have downloaded the package from:
http://swupdate.openvpn.org/community/releases/openvpn-2.3.6.tar.gz

extracted it and try to install it using command line terminal.

but the following error apperared:

**"configure: error:  ssl is required but missing**"

How can I solve this problem to complete openvpn-2.3.6 installation?

I'm following the instructions in the following link:
http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/

which uses the openvpn tool to configure the virtual tun interface.

Can I make tunnels and configure tun interface without the assestance of openvpn or any other tool.

do any one have simple example for using tun on ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 includes openvpn 2.3.2 (iirc the version number) `sudo apt-get install openvpn`... is there a reason this won't work for you?

Comment: With most software a minor version update is not a big deal. Not true for openvpn - big security fixes and enhancements in the minor revs.

Comment: I have just installed OpenVPN 2.4.7 from source in an Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS with no trouble, in case anyone needs it

Answer (score 131):

For the error "configure: error: ssl is required but missing"

You will need to install `libssl-dev`.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

For the error "configure: error: lzo enabled but missing"

```
sudo apt-get install liblzo2-dev
```

For the error "configure: error: libpam required but missing "

```
sudo apt-get install libpam0g-dev
```

Answer (score 6):

Let's see.

- First of all a fabulous up-and-running-on-ubuntu guide is
  [Setting up OpenVPN inside AWS-VPC](http://agiletesting.blogspot.com/2015/01/setting-up-openvpn-server-inside-aws-vpc.html). Most of it is not AWS specific. It also links to another guide which is pretty helpful too. Therein you will find the magic extra stuff you need

> apt-get install build-essential openssl libssl-dev lzop liblzo2-dev
>   libpam-dev

(pretty much as deadcode noted above).

- However, if you want to do it easy go to [Open VPN's Ubuntu Repository](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenvpnSoftwareRepos)

Answer (score 5):

Thank you deadcode - Your answer helped me -

On fedora 21 the packages were openssl-devel, lzo-devel and pam-devel

```
sudo yum install openssl-devel lzo-devel pam-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

openvpn 2.3.2 is the latest edition compatible with ubuntu 14.04. If you want to get the latest openvpn version in ubuntu 14.04,you can use the official DEB repository provided by OpenVPN to run the latest version of OpenVPN, 2.3.14.

Configure Apt to Use the Official OpenVPN Repository You can run the following as a regular Ubuntu user:

> wget -O - https://swupdate.openvpn.net/repos/repo-public.gpg | sudo
>   apt-key add -
>
> sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://swupdate.openvpn.net/apt trusty main" >
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn.list'
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install openvpn